# Copy files with deleting suffix in name

Tags: rename, cp

How can be done coping files that have some suffix at the end, into same dir with the smallest command possible:

Example have directory containing files:

- cassandra.yml.example
- database.yml.example
- facebook.yml.example
- cache.yml.example
- system.yml.example

need to copy them and have names like this:

- cassandra.yml
- database.yml
- facebook.yml
- cache.yml
- system.yml

Comment: I`ve figured about such thing: for x in ./config/*.example; do cp $x ./config/`basename $x .example`; done

Comment: you can even get rid of the `basename` call (at least with recent-enough `bash`):
`for x in ./config/*.example; do n=${x##*/}; cp $x dest/dir/${n%.example}; done`

Comment: If you use zsh, `zmv '(*).example' '$1'`

Answer (score 4):

```
for x in /path/to/*.example
do
  cp "$x" "${x%%.example}"
done
```

Will make a copy without the `.example` into the same folder as the source file.

Comment: This doesn't work with files with spaces

Comment: If the variables are inclosed in double quotes the spaces should be perserved.

Answer (score 0):

Requires `find` and a shell that supports string manipulation and process substitution (i.e. `Bash` and any compatible):

```
while read file
    do cp $file ${file%%.ext}
done < <(find -type f)
```

If you want to copy all files without extensions, you can use the glob (*) instead of ext.